# What is the correct way to include quotes in a Google Analytics Javascript field?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'Someone's Campaign');
```

The field above has a single quote but it may occasionally have a double quote (or even a mixture). I don't want to add slashes or to remove the quotes, and I cant see how using HTML special characters will help.

What is the solution?

Edit:

I said that I didn't want to add slashes because I thought that Analytics would think the slash was part of the string. However after using addslashes() from PHP to generate the string, it worked perfectly! I wish I understood why. Does GA have code to unescape the strings?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you include quotes in any other Javascript string. Either escape it:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'Someone\'s Campaign');
```

or use double quotes around the string:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', "Someone's Campaign");
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the single quote inside of the string:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'Someone\'s Campaign');
```